# Change audio file from UIPicker

Tags: uipickerview, avaudioplayer

I have a `UIPickerView` set up and running fine.  When the user selects a row I want one audio file to start but then if the user selects another row before the first audio file has stopped playing I want it to stop the first and just let the new audio file play.
I can do it at present with the code below but both files play at the same time and I cannot find a way of stopping the first one.

Am I going about the wrong way?  (I am new to SDK coding)

Any ideas would be appreciated
Thanks

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [list count];
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];


}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list2 objectAtIndex:row]];
    pickLabel.text = string;


    if(row == 1){



        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]

                          pathForResource:@"del08sample"ofType:@"mp3"];

        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]

                                   initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

        [theAudio play];


    }

    else if (row == 2){



        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]

                          pathForResource:@"icgi03sample"ofType:@"mp3"];

        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]

                                   initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];


        [theAudio play];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this with your code, but when I need to do this I add a simple check to see
if there is already an AVAudioPlayer that is playing and stop it before re-allocating. Apple's [AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) has a whole host of useful info too.

```
// stop sound if already playing

if (audioPlayer && audioPlayer.isPlaying) {

    [audioPlayer stop];

}
```